# New Zealand Visa : Medicals on Old Visa - Issues to File Visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passport-renewals, new-zealand, working-visas

I had done my medicals for New Zealand visa when my old passport was active last month. Then I got a new passport re-issued as I had to change personal details in the passport. Now the medicals have been shared to the INZ with the old passport number, which is now cancelled by Indian Passport Authorities after re-issuing me the new passport. Will this cause an issue while filing the visa when INZ sees the medicals are on old passport number but filing is done on a different passport number?
(Note: My new passport also contains my old passport number in it)